# How criteria restrictions for many to many mapping in hibernate enum

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

Enum class

```
public enum Days { SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY,SATURDAY }
```

Model class

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Days.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "bus_days", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bus_master_id"))
@Column(name = "day", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private Set<Days> days = new HashSet<Days>();
// getter setter
```

Error in hibernate query:

```
Criteria criteria = null;
 criteria = session.createCriteria(Model.class)
          .add(Restrictions.eq("fromCity.id", fromCity))
          .add(Restrictions.eq("toCity.id", toCity))
          .add(Restrictions.eq("days", days.ordinal()));//error in this line
            return (List<Model>) criteria.list();
```

Errors Obtained in eclipse console;

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 3
ERROR: No value specified for parameter 3
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Help Me,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't compare by `days.ordinal()`, you need to compare by `days` only, hibernate transform it to numbers by himself.

Comment: _thanq brother_